# How to play a tone for as long as the user holds a key?

Tags: .net, winapi, beep

Just for fun, I wrote a music program (in C#) that works by P/Invoking the [`Beep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the appropriate frequency when the user presses a key.

A problem with this approach is that `Beep` requires the duration to be specified up-front, so notes all have the same length.  This is a rather severe limitation for a musical instrument.

What I'd like to do start playing the note on a KeyDown event, and stop playing it on a KeyUp event.  Preferably, in a way that makes it possible to play multiple notes at the same time.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this in .NET or Win32?

Comment: One option i can think of with `Beep` is set a flag on keydown, start playing in a loop checking keydown flag, reset flag in keyup. you won't get real time stop, but can be adjusted for music purpose. Note: I have never tried this, you can try for fun if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Beep is not a good solution here. Generate short waveform files for required frequences, and then play them using PlaySound function with SND_LOOP flag like the following:

```
KeyDown: 
  PlaySound("wave440.wav", 0, SND_LOOP | SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
...
KeyUp: 
  PlaySound(NULL, 0, SND_PURGE);
```